# error: unknown option `--debug' React Native

Tags: react-native

I got "Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:" while trying to run my app on the device. Both "react-native run-android --stacktrace" and "react-native run-android --debug" yields "error: unknown option". Any ideas?

Comment: You can generate a signed apk and deploy it to your phone. Have you ever tried that? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Answer (score 2):

As for now,

> react-native run-android --help

Have only

> --install-debug

in available options.
Looks like this error message is outdated:

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the app with same package name in the emulator/device, uninstall the app from device/emulator and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
cd android
gradlew.bat  --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Native --stacktrace for Android**

*While in the root directory of your /app:*

```
> cd android
> ./gradlew --stacktrace
```

or

```
> cd android
> ./gradlew assembleDebug --info
```