# How to react-native run in debug mode immediately

Tags: react-native

I'm always running `react-native run-ios`, I tend to reset the emulator content and settings from time to time for regression purposes.

In order to go into debug mode, we have to CMD+D > Debug mode, but is there a command option so that the debugging mode is enabled right after `react-native run-ios` (fresh install) command?

Closest question I've found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345139/1405577 but it does not work

```
$ react-native run-ios --install-debug
error: unknown option \`--install-debug'
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any solutions or workarounds. I created a feature request that you could also support https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/option-to-start-simulator-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with `setIsDebuggingRemotely`from `NativeModules`:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

if (__DEV__) {
  NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true)
}
```

Then Debug JS Remotely will be activated on start.

Comment: For android need aditional steps `npm install --save react-native-devsettings-android` and `react-native link react-native-devsettings-android`